ceph says host is added, but it is not
I have a cephadm-managed ceph-cluster consisting of 2 nodes.
When trying to add a third node, cephadm says it was successful:
main@node01:~$ sudo ceph orch host add node03 10.0.0.155
Added host 'node03' with addr '10.0.0.155'

Checking the cluster however shows this isn't the case:
main@node01:~$ sudo ceph node ls
{
    "mon": {
        "node01": [
            "node01"
        ],
        "node02": [
            "node02"
        ]
    },
    "osd": {},
    "mgr": {
        "node01": [
            "node01.gnxkpe"
        ],
        "node02": [
            "node02.tdjwgc"
        ]
    }
}

What's going on here?
